# d3js update and maintain structure of visualization

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to (and if yes - how to fix render()) to perform properly updating divs after click on [x] with d3?

```
    var id_names = {},
    render = function (id) {
      var names = id_names[id],
          divs = d3.select("#filelist").selectAll("div").data(names),
          denter = divs.enter().append("div");

      denter.append("div")
        .classed("txt", true);
      denter.append("div")
        .classed("del", true);

      divs.select("div .txt")
        .text(function (d, i) {return i + " :: " + d});
      divs.select("div .del")
        .text("[x]")
        .on("click", function (d, i) {
          // remove element from array
          id_names[id].splice(i, 1)
          render(id)
        });

      divs.exit().remove()
    };

    // {id: [name, nameN]}
    id_names[11] = ["aaa", "bbb", "cc"]
    render(11)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have an `update()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you bind the `data` to `div`s, and you have more `div`s in the `denter`s.

So if you add some `class` (or `id`) to the containing `div`s, you get the desired effect (I hope).

See here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chroth/bskejkwc/1/)

Or here, the core changes:

```
divs = d3.select("#filelist").selectAll(".container")
        .data(name),
denter = divs.enter().append("div")
        .attr('class', 'container');
```

(A side note: I am not a fan of modifying **in** a function that is in an outside scope, as you are doing it with `id_name` here...). This may lead to very nasty side effects...)

Hope this helps!